# How to increment a counter from another route/page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, state, bloc, cubit

I'm using Bloc/Cubit (flutter_bloc) & Auto_Router packages

I have the counter on the /counter route and FloatingActionButtons on a /user_profile route to increment the counter.

How can I increment the counter from a different page/route? I should be able to switch back and forth between pages and increment/decrement from either page but I'm getting the following error message:

> Exception has occurred.
> ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this UserProfilePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that UserProfilePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
)

Here is my code:

home_page.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsScaffold(
      appBarBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) => AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        title: const Text('FlutterBottomNav'),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: const AutoBackButton(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      routes: const [
        CounterRouter(),
        PostsRouter(),
        UsersRouter(),
        SettingsRouter(),
      ],
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
        return SalomonBottomBar(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20,
            vertical: 40,
          ),
          currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
          items: [
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.plus_one, size: 30),
              title: const Text('Counter'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.post_add, size: 30),
              title: const Text('Posts'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.blue[200],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Users'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

counter_cubit.dart

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  CounterCubit() : super(0);

  void increment() => emit(state + 1);
  void decrement() => emit(state - 1);
}
```

counter_page.dart

```
class CounterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
      child: const CounterView(),
    );
  }
}

class CounterView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final l10n = context.l10n;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(l10n.counterAppBarTitle)),
      body: const Center(child: CounterText()),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_star_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('star');
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.star),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_boat_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('boat');
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.sailing),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_increment_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_decrement_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final count = context.select((CounterCubit cubit) => cubit.state);
    return Text('$count', style: theme.textTheme.headline1);
  }
}
```

user_profile_page.dart

```
class UserProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int userId;
  const UserProfilePage({
    Key? key,
    @PathParam() required this.userId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = User.users[userId - 1];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: user.color,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            UserAvatar(
              avatarColor: Colors.white,
              username: 'user${user.id}',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_star_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('star');
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.star),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_boat_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () {
              print('boat');
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.sailing),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_increment_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          FloatingActionButton(
            key: const Key('counterView_decrement_floatingActionButton'),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

any help greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to below code

ValueNotifer & ValueListenableBuilder can be used to hold value and update widget by notifying its listeners and reducing number of times widget tree getting rebuilt.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
final ValueNotifier<int> counter = ValueNotifier(0);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FloatingActionButtonClass(),
    );
  }
}

class FloatingActionButtonClass extends StatelessWidget {
  void _incrementCounter() {
    counter.value++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.

      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
            );
          },
          child: Text("Floating Action Button"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: counter,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Text(
                  counter.value.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can explore more about ValueNotifier and ValueListenable Builder by below mentioned link. https://medium.flutterdevs.com/exploring-valuelistenablebuilder-in-flutter-9a16fc4c4c5b

Comment: thank you very much! seems leaner your way, i'm going to read up on ValueNotifier and ValueListenable Builder thanks to you!

Comment: Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a BlocProvider and move the view to a child.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
      child: const HomePageView(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePageView extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsScaffold(
      appBarBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) => AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        title: const Text('FlutterBottomNav'),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: const AutoBackButton(),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      routes: const [
        CounterRouterB(),
        CounterRouter(),
        PostsRouter(),
        UsersRouter(),
        SettingsRouter(),
      ],
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
        return SalomonBottomBar(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20,
            vertical: 40,
          ),
          currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
          items: [
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.redAccent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.plus_one, size: 30),
              title: const Text('Counter2'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.plus_one, size: 30),
              title: const Text('Counter'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.amberAccent,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.post_add, size: 30),
              title: const Text('Posts'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.blue[200],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.person,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Users'),
            ),
            SalomonBottomBarItem(
              selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent[100],
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                size: 30,
              ),
              title: const Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is this a decent solution or is it clunky?